# Speed up parsing json to class object

Tags: json, vba

Sticking to Excel, I am parsing response text to custom objects using vba-json. Sometimes there are thousands of objects in the json string. Using `application.ontime` recursively to run some less expensive status requests in intervals of only a few seconds so efficiency is important. 
Simply parsing the data to an array is fast but gets expensive and complex the more the data needs to be manipulated. 
I’m looking for outside the box efficiencies beyond the standard “speed up excel” stuff. 
An example would be parsing the json objects to a class property with getters pointing to the property inside the json object.

```
Private jStr

Public property let JSON(value)
Set jStr = value
End property

Public property get Name() as string
Name = jStr(“name”)
End property

Public property get ID() as string
ID = jStr(“id”)
End property
```

Instead of assigning variables, I just pass in the parsed string.

I have tried various combinations of collections, nested collections/arrays/arraylists and while the differences in some cases are seemingly insignificant, the right combination of types will help a lot when repeated thousands of times.

If anyone has suggestions please chime in. If I’m going about this the wrong way and someone needs to wear me out about it then by all means... be my guest. I just need some creative thinking. Obviously if I step outside of VBA then this isn’t a problem but here we are...

Comment: Only comment I have at the moment is to be careful when using collection methods on large datasets (I can't say how large though..)  It is best to manually loop with counters instead, or you may get poorly defined errors with code that otherwise works on smaller data sets.

Comment: Interesting. I must be under the mark because that is something I have yet to experience. VBA is full of little treats like that so it’s no surprise. 
I’ve built everything I need in a very nice WPF application but my company doesn’t want to add additional software so I’m stuck. Maybe I’ll just use my app to load a workbook and query that. Nobody needs to know how the data became available. Lol